# Virtual memory utilization for Outlook process on Win7 & Win10 OS machines

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, 32-bit

I am having VSTO outlook plugin which loads html form with email window.

On Win7 (64 bit OS) machine with Outlook 2010 (32 bit), I am able to open approximately 25 email windows with html form and then outlook gets hanged or crashed as by then it reaches to max memory utilization which is 2 GB. I have verified with VMMAP tool.

On Win 10 (64 bit OS) machine with Outlook 2016 (32 bit), I am able to open 45 windows and still see 500 MB free memory and utilized around 3.5 GB on VMMAP which indicates that with Win 10 and outlook 2016 getting 4 GB VM.

Is this something for 32 bit application, virtual memory size got increased to 4 GB from 2 GB with Win 7? I tried to find out reference articles for this but no luck so far.

Thanks for your help.

Regards,
Manoj

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from other forum. I have summarized below with that link.

--> If the Outlook 2016 32 bit executable has been linked with /LARGEADDRESSAWARE (Handle Large Addresses) then a 64 bit version of Windows will give the process a 4GB address space.

--> To confirm application got linked with /LARGEADDRESSAWARE, on visual studio command prompt usecommand like below - dumpbin /headers outlook.exe | more where it  displays text "Application can  handle large (>2 GB) addresses.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/22def687-9f0c-4692-b053-0a50efda8f51/virtual-memory-utilization-for-outlook-process-on-win7-amp-win10?forum=vsto

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050601-24/?p=35483

Thanks,
Manoj